# Parse every column of a .csv file into a single list python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.4

I have a following type of csv

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I would like to parse every column of this csv file into a list with out columns so the end result would be

```
myList = ["1","4","7","2","5","8","3","6","9"]
```

I have found many solutions for one column but i need to be flexible to be able to read every column of the file. I'm using an older version of python so i can't use any solutions with pandas library.

Comment: There is no direct way to do this, you have to loop through each row and add that in single `array`

Answer (score 5):

You could read the file fully and then `zip` the rows to transpose them, then chain the result to flatten the list. Standalone example (using a list of strings as input):

```
import csv,itertools

text="""a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
""".splitlines()

myList = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*csv.reader(text[1:]))))

print(myList)
```

result:

```
['1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '8', '3', '6', '9']
```

from a file it would read:

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f,separator=",")  # comma is by default, but just in case...
    next(cr)  # skip title
    myList = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*cr)))
```

Comment: splitlines() was just to create a standalone example. you don't need splitlines for a file. Check my second example where the input is a file. Don't use a `DictReader` because the order of the values would depend on the order of the keys, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code, but i get ['1;2;3', '4;5;6', '7;8;9'], nvm ... excel was screwing me over ... it added a ';' instead of ','

Comment: that's because your file doesn't match the file you posted. Try adding a separator (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

```
d = """a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
"""

cells = []
for line in d.split("\n"):
    if line:
        cells.append(line.strip().split(','))

print(cells)

for n in range(len(cells[0])):
    for r in cells:
        print(r[n])
```

---

Same iteration, but as generator:

```
def mix(t):
    for n in range(len(t[0])):
        for r in t:
            yield r[n]

print( list( mix(cells) )  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `csv` and `chain` to flatten the list

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

l = list(csv.reader(open('text.csv', 'r')))
mylist = map(list, zip(*l[1:])) # transpose list
list(chain.from_iterable(mylist)) # output ['1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '8', '3', '6', '9']
```